# arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line для 64 бит

Tags: c#, android, c++, unity3d

Ищу ошибки в il2cpp билде Unity под андроид, согласно этому руководству
https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000292166-Symbolicate-Android-crash

В нем указывается 32 битный короткий адрес 0043a05c, который после выполнения следующей команды

```
> ./arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -f -C -e   /Applications/Unity.app/Content/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Release/Symbols/armeabi-v7a/libunity.sym.so 0043a05c
```

Расшифровывается во вполне читаемый

```
Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*)  18:06:51.501: I/DEBUG(242):
```

Но с тех пор Юнити успело изрядно развится и теперь собирается под ARM64, и в случае с моими крашами, адреса памяти теперь вот такие

```
00000000001f6f34
```

У юнити есть библиотеки для расшифровки и под 32 бита, и под 64. Обе называются одинаково - libunity.sym.so, просто лежат в разных папках - armeabi-v7 для 32 бит и arm64-v8a для 64 бит.

Но вот в чем неприятность - когда я пытаюсь скормить addr2line 64 битную библиотеку - оно ругается что

```
 C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm64-v8a\libunity.sym.so: File format not recognized
```

Когда же я использую 32 битную либу, то все проходит ок

```
$  ./arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -f -C -e   "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\armeabi-v7a\libunity.sym.so" 00000000001f6f34
mbedtls::SuiteTLSModule_MbedtlskUnitTestCategory::Testpubkey_ParsePem_Return_Object_And_Raise_NoError_ForPEMEncodedObjectWithoutNullTerminationHelper::RunImpl()
??:?
```

Но адрес скорее всего неправильный - так как я пытаюсь расшифровать длинный адрес, используя 32 битную либу. Да и сам краш юнити в дебаг режиме говорит мне что стектрейс у этого краша другой

```
 00000000001f6f34  /data/app/сcom.myappName/lib/arm64/libunity.so (DebugStringToFilePostprocessedStacktrace(DebugStringToFileData const&)+872)
```

В связи с этим, несколько вопросов.

1. Есть ли 64 битная addr2line или какой то аналогичный инструмент? Или она уже и 32 и 64, и это я просто что то делаю не так?
2. Почему libunity.sym.so из папки х64 не читается addr2line, говоря что неподдерживаемый формат файла? А из папки х32 читается, хотя название и формат - одно и тоже! (libunity.sym.so)

3)Если ли более нормальные инструменты, возможно в гуях, чтобы выбрать либу для расшифровки, выбрать стектрейс - и она сама достала из стектрейса адреса памяти и преобразовала их в читаемый стектрейс?

PS:
Подсказки у тегов сломались. Не могу ничего выбрать, поэтому пишу тэги как помню

Comment: А обычные средства отладки не работают?

Comment: @user7860670 надо получить данные из крэшлога, доступа для отладки к самому устройству и возможности повторить это как то иначе- нет

Comment: тогда вам нужен не крашлог, а крашдамп

Comment: @user7860670 Он есть - но в нем те же самые адреса памяти, без названий. Мне и нужно средство перевести это в читаемый стектрейс, чтобы понять что привело к крашу.

Comment: это должно автоматически происходить в отладчике. Может вы ему файлы с символами не подсовывали?

Comment: @user7860670 это часть моего вопроса
`3)Если ли более нормальные инструменты, возможно в гуях, чтобы выбрать либу для расшифровки, выбрать стектрейс - и она сама достала из стектрейса адреса памяти и преобразовала их в читаемый стектрейс?`
Расскажите, каким отладчиком и как пользоваться, чтобы прочитать крэшдамп приложения на андроиде, написанного под arm64. 
Есть сам дамп(текстовой файл, начинающийся со слов Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 26620 (UnityMain), pid 26507 ), есть символы для расшифровки( libunity.sym.so).

Comment: Да любым отладчиком - gdb, lldb. Вроде отладка дампов - частый и хорошо описанный сценарий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл нужную утилиту под 64 бита.
Если 32-битная утилита находилась тут

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line.exe
```

то 64 бита находится тут

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-addr2line.exe
```

И называется немного по другому  - aarch64-linux-android-addr2line. Несмотря на то что в названии утилиты нет слова arm, она успешно расшифровывает стектрейсы из под arm64-v8 и нормально воспринимает символы для arm64-v8

В остальном команды такие же, т.е.

```
./aarch64-linux-android-addr2line -f -C -e   "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm64-v8a\libunity.sym.so" 00000000001f6f34
```

Выдает нормальный стектрейс для адреса памяти 00000000001f6f34